# git log report going back to the start of project

Tags: git

Is there a way with git to get a log report going back a few months or going back from your entire project to date of all your pushes to the master branch.

Comment: Do you mean pushes, or do you mean commits?

Comment: pushes to the master or a branch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have just the beginning, you can do `git log --reverse`.

Note though that if you try git log -5 --reverse, you will get the last 5, which are then reversed. If you'd like say 5 first commits, you can do something like

```
git --no-pager log --reverse --oneline | head -5
```

(giving suitable parameters to log for information that you want to see).

If you just want a defined timespan, you can do something like

```
git log --since=2.months.ago --until=1.day.ago
```

Answer (score 1):

`git` itself doesn't keep a log of pushes. Depending on what push transports are in use (http, git+ssh, or git-daemon), you can probably gather that information from appropriate log files if the log file entries have been made (and still exist). If not, you could at least reconfigure them to log in the future.

Comment: If you're using Github, I know they've *got* the data, since it shows up in the activity log. Don't know of a way to see the activity stream for a single repo, though. May be worth a message to their support.

Comment: @Emily The activity stream is composed from commit information, such as author and commit timestamps.  There's nothing they show that requires any information except what is in the commit history.

Comment: I've seen two 'pushed to master' events from the same user on the same repo without anything else in between, which suggests otherwise. http://cl.ly/273t1L351f2r2H183Y2G for example. Doesn't mean the full list is accessible, but it may be somewhere to start if the poster is using Github.

Answer (score 0):

`git log origin/master` will show the entire lineage of the remote master branch, which will include anything you have pushed to master (assuming that master was never rewound).

Comment: This only gives me the last 5 pushes.

Comment: There was only a short list didn't need to scroll

Comment: If that is the case then `origin/master` only contains five commits.  Also, a "push" is not some unit of history -- it is an action that will transfer any new commit objects in your repository to some other repository.  You cannot enumerate "push actions taken" anymore than you can enumerate "log actions taken".